# How to compare colors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't this work? Even though the colour *is* equal to `#ECECF4` it still alerts "No".
It is selecting the corrent element as I have tested it. Is there a better way to write this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function weekclick() {
    if (document.getElementById('w1').style.backgroundColor == "#ECECF4") {
        alert("Yes");
    } else {
        alert("No");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where is this script placed / when is it running?

Comment: It is placed here
<div id="w1" onclick="weekclick()">1<br /></div>
And runs on click

Comment: @Teemu `#ececf4` will only works with IE.

Comment: I have the same problem. Changing this to lower case didnt fix it.

Answer (score 17):

**Comparing colors as part of the business logic should be avoided at all cost.**

Instead, keep the logic in JavaScript and act according to a state kept somewhere. Then, if you want to send a visual feedback to the user through a change of color, add a class to the element. That way, JavaScript only knows about class names and the styling is always isolated in the CSS as it should.

```js
$(".list").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.list li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.list li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.list li.active {
  background-color: #eeeecc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
```

---

That being said, OP's code works for me with Chrome 17.0.963.56 and Firefox 8.0. When you don't know what to compare, just use `console.log()` to see what it looks like.

Note that `#ECECF4` is the same color as `rgb(236, 236, 244)` but in a different representation.

**IE7 and IE8 output the HEX value**, IE9 and up and other browsers output the RGB format. So comparing color with cross-browser compatibility is a tricky task and the [best way to do it isn't beautiful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943970/1218980).

I made a simple function which works for most cases with most browser, even with color set through CSS.

```js
function weekclick() {
    var elemColor = getStyle(this, "backgroundColor"),
        color = "rgb(238, 238, 204)";

    console.log("Broswer returned elem color: ", elemColor);

    // IE7 and IE8 output the hex value
    if (elemColor.slice(0, 1) === '#') elemColor = hexToRgb(elemColor);

    console.log(elemColor, " === ", color, "?", elemColor === color);
}

// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41354868/1218980
// Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744598/1218980
function getStyle(el, prop) {
    return (typeof getComputedStyle !== 'undefined' ?
        getComputedStyle(el, null) :
        el.currentStyle
    )[prop];
}


// Slightly modified version to quickly return a string
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/1218980
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? "rgb(" + [
        parseInt(result[1], 16),
        parseInt(result[2], 16),
        parseInt(result[3], 16)
    ].join(', ') + ")" : null;
}
```

```css
#css-div {
  background-color: #eeeecc;
}
```

```html
<div style="Background-color:#eeeecc" onclick="javascript:weekclick.call(this);">#eeeecc</div>
<div style="Background-color:#EEC" onclick="javascript:weekclick.call(this);">#EEC</div>
<div style="background-color:hsla(60, 50%, 86.7%, 1)" onclick="javascript:weekclick.call(this);">hsla(60, 50%, 86.7%, 1)</div>
<div style="background-color:rgb(238, 238, 204)" onclick="javascript:weekclick.call(this);">rgb(238, 238, 204)</div>
<div id="css-div" onclick="javascript:weekclick.call(this);">css</div>
```

I call the `weekclick` function with `javascript:weekclick.call(this)` passing the element itself as the context of the callback, making it easy to access the element with `this`.

It could be extended to take alpha into account when using HSLA or RGBA.

---

*When I originally wrote this answer back in 2012, I used `navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer"` to know if it was IE7 and the color to compare was changed to its HEX equivalent. Don't do that as it won't work today.*

Answer (score 4):

## Use a `canvas` to compare colors.

- Fill one pixel using the ***color string***
- and the other pixel using the ***Element `getComputedStyle` color property***.
- Compare the two pixels `data` using `Array.from` and `JSON.stingify`

```js
/**
 * Test if Element color property holds a specific color.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/60689673/383904
 * 
 * @param {Object} el The DOM Node Element
 * @param {String} prop A CSS property color property
 * @param {String} color A valid CSS color value
 * @return {Boolean} True if element color matches
 */
function isElPropColor(el, prop, color) {
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 1, 1 );
  ctx.fillStyle = getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
  ctx.fillRect( 1, 0, 1, 1 );
  const a = JSON.stringify(Array.from(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data));
  const b = JSON.stringify(Array.from(ctx.getImageData(1, 0, 1, 1).data));
  ctx.canvas = null;
  return a === b;
}


// TEST (PS: see CSS!):

const el   = document.body;
const prop = 'background-color';

console.log(isElPropColor(el, prop, 'red'));      // obviously true :)
console.log(isElPropColor(el, prop, '#f00'));                  // true
console.log(isElPropColor(el, prop, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'));        // true
console.log(isElPropColor(el, prop, 'hsl(0, 100%, 50%)'));     // true
console.log(isElPropColor(el, prop, 'hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1)')); // true
```

```css
body {background: red; }
```

#### The buts and whys

*Most* modern browsers calculate and convert the color value to **RGB/A**.
But we should **not rely on doing** strict **equality comparison** like:

```
 // (Say the element is really red)
 const isRed = myElement.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255,0,0)"; // false
```

- False because it's actually "rgb(255, 0, 0)", with spaces.
- No guarantee some browser tomorrow will not convert to "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)", or HSLA perhaps?
- Edge and IE will return the value used in CSS or overwritten by our JS

#### We cannot reliably compare two DIV styles using `getComputedStyle`

and we cannot even create an "in-memory" DIV element since we need to - append it to the DOM, than use `getComputedStyle(tempDIVElement, null).getPropertyValue('background-color')` and than remove it from the DOM. It's a waste of DOM recalculations, paints, and it's not guaranteed some wondering stylesheet `!important` did not messed up our temporary DIV styles `div {background: fuchsia !important; }` giving false-positives *"Is red? True! blue is blue because of !important"*.

#### Why canvas?

- A canvas can stay in memory. No need to append to DOM, set colors, remove element.
- The returned **pixel data** is always guaranteed to be `[R, G, B, A]` (RGBA being 0-255 values)
- A wondering CSS rule will not mess up the assigned color

#### Useful links:

- [Canvas_API <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)
- [CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)
- [Array/from <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [JSON/stringify <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [Window/getComputedStyle <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually just learning javascript, but instead of creating a function that converted rgb() to hex you can create a div of the same background-color you are looking for and compared it to that div's background color. If you happen to already have a div of that hex value you can just do this:

```
//javascript
if (document.getElementId('desiredElementToCompare').style.backgroundColor === document.getElementId('elementWithTheDesiredHexString').style.backgroundColor)

//jQuery
if ($('#desiredElementToCompare').css('background-color') === $('#elementWithTheDesiredHexString').css('background-color')
```

You can create a div with a function and then do the comparison like this:

```
var compareHex = (hex) => {
    var hexString = document.createElement('div')
    hexString.style.backgroundColor = `${hex}`
    return hexString.style.backgroundColor
}
//then compare
//javascript
if (document.getElementId('desiredElementToCompare').style.backgroundColor === compareHex("#ECECF4"))

//jQuery
if($('#desiredElementToCompare').css('background-color') === compareHex("#ECECF4")
```

Comment: While this works well without much addition to the code, I find it inefficient to grab another element in the page for the sole purpose of comparing their colors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer could help. Convert the color code to hex and then compare each RGB color/channel (i don't know the word)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666938/1757214

I think is better and easy compare two numbers than two strings

Answer (score 0):

This way suggests using JQuery's `background-color` which standardises the response to `rgb(r, g, b)`.

[How to get the background color of an element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no standard how

```js
const color = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

is defined. It is a string but nothing is said how this string is formatted. Currently it seems to be `rgba(000, 000, 000, 000)` where the spaces *are* essential. This is either a deliberate or accidental omission in the ECMAScript standard.

There are a number of libraries out there that try to alleviate this.

- https://github.com/colorjs/color-parse
- https://gist.github.com/neolitec/1344610/3a3a9dc7d94644ff48f12cc7823b79f2b8ea17ac

but those might not exist or be maintained when you read this. They do use the browser to include new elements, set a color in any shape or form and read out the actual color used. It would be so much easier if every browser gave of a way of turning any color in any format into a canonical format (like a Color object prototype). Our only hopes are that the [EcmaScript team](https://ecma-international.org/) come up with some kind of Color object with the proper parse and toString() function to make up for this.

Comment: ECMAScript doesn't have anything to do with the format of CSS values, rather they're defined in [CSS standards](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#the-color-property).

Answer (score -3):

I would advice using the '===' stric equal (i think this is the name).

Like:

```
if (document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor === "rgb(236, 236, 244)") {
```