# How to get element width/height with margin, padding, border in Native JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom

Looking for reliable method to calculate the element's width/height + margin - padding + border using native JS only and be xbrowser (IE8+)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you're only dealing with pixel values for the margin, padding and border properties, you can do the following:

```
// we're assuming a reference to your element in a variable called 'element'
var style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = element.offsetWidth, // or use style.width
    margin = parseFloat(style.marginLeft) + parseFloat(style.marginRight),
    padding = parseFloat(style.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(style.paddingRight),
    border = parseFloat(style.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(style.borderRightWidth);

alert(width + margin - padding + border);
```

If you're dealing with other kinds of values (like ems, points or values like `auto`), I would like to refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489393/3565383).

Comment: +1 I liked it since you have covered all the points, although you could have mentioned `element.getBoundingClientRect` function, in your answer.

Comment: Remember you have to declare the widths as `border-left-width` or `border-right-width` in css though. It will not parse left width from a style declared as `border-width` or simply `border`.

Comment: The ´element.offsetWidth´ already includes the sizes of the borders, but in your last codeline you sum up the borders again. You added the border width twice. Perhaps better use ´clientWidth´ instead ´offsetWidth´.