# why is my javascript if else statement not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

could someone tell me what is wrong with my code below please? I want 'the_text' to be visible or invisible on the button click. The mystyle.css has:

```
#the_text {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And my html page:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <button type="button" onClick = "check_this_out()">Show/hide</button>
>
> <div id="the_text"> I want to hide this by pressing the button above</div>
>
> <script>
> function check_this_out() {
> var vis_or_hidden = document.getElementById("the_text");
>
> if vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] = "hidden"
>
> {vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] = "visible"}
>
> else
>
> {vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] = "hidden"}
>  }
> </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: `=` does an assignment, `==` or `===` do a comparison.

Comment: if(vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] == "hidden")

Comment: Also, the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) only contains values for inline styles. For values inherited from a stylesheet, you'll have to get the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Thanks for that. But why am I getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: check_this_out is not defined' when it is defined? And thanks for the down votes, whoever it is. Sorry I'm not a genius like you guys.

Comment: @user3481992 There's a syntax error with the `if` statement in the `function` definition, so it fails to become available to the `onClick`. There are a few validators that can help resolve, such as [JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Comment: thanks for that, looking at jshint now, looks interesting. feel free to post the above in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In fact, == does not work. It should be =. With #the_text {
visibility: hidden;} in mystyle.css, and function check_this_out() {
var vis_or_hidden = document.getElementById("the_text");
{vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] = "visible"}} it works correctly, the div becomes visible. It has to do with my if syntax. I'll post with answer when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the `function` definition.

- The first is a syntax error as [`if` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) require parenthesis around the condition.

  ```
  if (vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] = "hidden")
  ```
- The next is that the condition is actually [assigning (`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) rather than [comparing (`==`, `===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

  ```
  if (vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"] == "hidden")
  ```

  > Note: `if` statements don't require a boolean condition, so you won't get a type error to highlight between them. However, since literals can't be assigned to, reversing the operands can:
  >
  > ```
  > if ("hidden" = vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"])
  > // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
  > ```
  >
  > vs.
  >
  > ```
  > if ("hidden" == vis_or_hidden.style["visibility"])
  > ```
- The last is a common gotcha with the DOM, as the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) only represents the element's own inline styles, and it doesn't yet have a `visibility` of its own. To include styles inherited from a stylesheet, you'll have to determine the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

  ```
  if (window.getComputedStyle(vis_or_hidden)["visibility"] == "hidden")
  ```

  > Note, however, that `getComputedStyle()` isn't supported in [IE8 and older](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility). For cross-browser compatibility, you'll have to mix in [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231.aspx).
  >
  > One option for this is [Quirks Mode's `getStyle()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html). Another is [taking a snippet from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489393/15031). But, there are many other shims and polyfills available to be found.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae426/ (Note the `No wrap` option when using `onclick`.)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. No doubt I'll mark it correct when I get my head around it. I'm still on the part about '=' and '==', which is weird, because '=' works for me so far, and '==' does not.

Comment: @user3481992 It still works to an extent because the assignment returns the value being assigned for the `if` to test on. So, the condition becomes `if ("hidden")`. And, since `"hidden"` is a string that isn't empty, it's considered *truthy* (as in, `Boolean("hidden") === true`). But, then the condition will always pass, so the `else` block won't be executed.

Comment: Brilliant, your code works great, now I'm going to try understand the differences between =, == and ===. What do you mean 'no wrap' option? I looked at your jsfiddle and couldn't see anything in that regard.

Comment: @user3481992 On the left side in the menu under "Frameworks & Extensions." It's something specific to JSFiddle, but the default choice of `onLoad` can conflict with `on*` attributes like `onclick`.

Comment: Ah yes, see what you mean.