# cannot return css property of HTML element

Tags: javascript, css

There is element in HTML: `<div id="block"></div>`, and it's property via CSS:

```
#block { 
    background: red;
 }
```

If I want to assign in JavaScript to some variable a property from CSS, like this:

```
var value = document.getElementById('block').style.background // It doesn't work
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you forgot a `d`. Is document not ocument ;)

Comment: BTW: For color, use `background-color` in CSS and `backgroundColor` in Javascript.

Comment: it doesn't work for any CSS properties

Comment: The `style` object only contains *local* styles - those set *directly* on the element. Getting the effective style as cascaded through all style sheets is somewhat of a pain, and differs between (old) IE and other browsers. This is one of the more useful things that a framework can help you with.

Comment: @JacobLutin: That is because it is via CSS. See Pointy's comment above and j08691's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
var value = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('block')).getPropertyValue("background-color");
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733365/cross-browser-ie8-getcomputedstyle-with-javascript) for Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use single line of jQuery for this :

```
var value = $("#block").css("background-color");
```

Comment: How is it in any way related to the question?

Comment: Whenever we assign background:<color>; to element, it is stored as background-color property of that element. And as per question,JacobLutin wanted to extract the value of property background-color of the div#block and assign it to some variable. And var value = $("#block").css("background-color"); does the required.

Comment: I meant the question is not tagged jQuery. The question is about not being able to get the property via 'style' property in Javascript.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Mistakenly did not focused on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery on your project I recommend using .css() jquery function

Eg.:
Setting css

```
$('#block').css({background:'black'});
```

Getting css:

```
var cssValues = $('#block').css('background'});
```

See more about this [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: How is it in any way related to the question?

Comment: Did you see the "Getting css" section?

Comment: I meant the question is not tagged jQuery. The question is about not being able to get the property via 'style' property in Javascript.

Comment: Got it, and yes it only applies "If you can use jQuery on your project". 
Sometimes different approaches are useful

Answer (score -2):

You can try this -

```
var  block = document.getElementById("block");
block.setAttribute("style","background-color: red;");
```

Comment: I don't need to assign property to element, I need to return it don't changing propery in javascript.