# Javascript: onClick checkbox change div color

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick

I've a check-box inside div.

```
<div id="question_text_1">
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(question_text_1)">Sample question text
</div>
```

I'm trying to toggle the background color of `div` whenever checkbox is checked or unchecked, which is not working.

Here is the [complete code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNeMML)

However, implementing same code without toggle logic is working fine - [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGamma)

Kindly suggest what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `x.style.backgroundColor` will return color's value only if it is set as inline style. And it will return rgb, not hex. You should better make the verification based on `checked` attribute of the checkbox:

```
<div id="question_text_1">
    <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(question_text_1, this)">Sample question text
</div>

function myFunction(x, _this) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = _this.checked ? '#0000FF' : '#FF0000';
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avLrze

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't work because `x.style.backgroundColor` always returns `''`- empty string and `else` block is executed.

To get the values see [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

---

You can achieve this using CSS, no need of using Javascript

1. Wrap the text associated with the checkbox in `label` element
2. Use `:checked` property of the checkbox to apply styles when the checkbox is checked
3. Use adjacent sibling selector(`+`), on checked checkbox to set styles on the label

```css
:checked + label {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="question_text_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
  <label for="check1">Sample question text</label>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use Javascript, use `classList`

1. Create a class with desired styles to be applied when checked
2. Use `!important` to override styles in the class as the id selector have higher specificity
3. Use `classList.toggle` to toggle class

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epGaOb)

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('blue');
}
```

```css
#question_text_1 {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 7px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #00f !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="question_text_1">
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(question_text_1)">Sample question text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please change you code like below,It works fine

```
<div id="question_text_1">
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(question_text_1,this)">Sample question text
</div>

 function myFunction(x,y) {
  if (y.checked)
      x.style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
  else
      x.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
```

You can not directly compare div background color with value of color because for it you must have to declare variable of color related to different browser
for that visit this link 
[How to compare a backgroundColor in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-a-backgroundcolor-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with jQuery like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox"/>
<div id="toggle_color">Color Will change here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#my_checkbox').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $("#toggle_color").css('background-color',"red");
        } else {
            $("#toggle_color").css('background-color',"#fff");
        }
    })
})
```

Checkout the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/843czdok/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **x.style.backgroundColor** in if condition use **window.getComputedStyle(x).backgroundColor** and compare with 'rgb' equivalent of colors.

```
function myFunction(x) {
 if (window.getComputedStyle(x).backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
 } else if (window.getComputedStyle(x).backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 255)"){
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Dont you think it will be an expensive operation ?

Comment: This may be slow but works in most of the cases for pure javascript.
If you can use jQuery - go with .css property.

Check this link for performance

https://jsperf.com/getcomputedstyle-vs-style-vs-css/2

Comment: How about `this.checked` ?

Comment: Yes that will work. We need to have conditional function to change background color when checked.

But question was about what could be used in place of     style.backgroundColor so I gave an option of     window.getComputedStyle.