# Change DIV color checkbox onclick IN LOOP

Tags: javascript, php, css, checkbox

I have searched for several hours now trying to implent scripts to change the div background. I've found this solution which works when it's not in a loop:

[Javascript: onClick checkbox change div color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162961/javascript-onclick-checkbox-change-div-color/33163181#33163181)

The challenge here is that the checkboxes is in a foreach loop with unique id values.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function myFunction(x, _this) {
  if (_this.checked) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
  } else  {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
  }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#result {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 7px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
    $SL = 0;
    foreach($results_resultat as $key => $row_resultat) { ?>
<div id="result">
  <input type="checkbox" name="res_id[]" value="<?php echo $row_resultat['id']; ?>" onChange="myFunction(result, this)">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

With this code it will show all the rows which are selected from the tabel but it won't change the div color when clicking the checkbox.

Help is very much appreciated. :-)

Comment: `result` isn’t defined.

Comment: Change `result` to `document.getElementById('result')`

Comment: @Xufox, `result` will be referring to the div element with id `result` as browsers add elements with ids to the global scope as that id. The problem is they are creating multiple divs  with the same id so only one gets affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same id `result` to wrap all your checkbox elements. `id`s should be unique, use `class="result"` instead to wrap your checkbox elements. Plus, you don't have to send anything except `this` to `myFunction` function. So change your code in the following way,

**CSS**

```
.result {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 7px;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $SL = 0;
    foreach($results_resultat as $key => $row_resultat) { ?>
        <div class="result">
            <input type="checkbox" name="res_id[]" value="<?php echo $row_resultat['id']; ?>" onChange="myFunction(this)">
        </div>
        <?php 
    } 
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(_this) {
    if (_this.checked) {
        _this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
    } else  {
        _this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.. :-)   Can you tell me how I can make the change by clicking the DIV layer? I have tried with:   <div class="result" onClick="myFunction(this)">  but this only colored the whole page

Comment: I found the solution.. And of course it's so simple as just put <label> around it and id it.. :-)   So the result to this is:  <label ="res_id[]">
        <div class="result">
            <input type="checkbox" name="res_id[]" id="res_id[]" value="<?php echo $row_resultat['id']; ?>" onChange="myFunction(this)" class="trans">
        </div>
 </label>    Well I also added a class which the actual checkbox transparent..

Comment: @Kenneth Glad my answer helped you in resolving the issue. :-) *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that line: `onChange="myFunction(result, this)"`.
At that line result is not defined, usually it is common to pass a string with selector, or string with an id.
Something like that `onChange="myFunction('result', this)"`

And then in you `JS` function use `document.getElementById` to get a reference to the DOM element.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function myFunction(id, _this) {
  if (_this.checked) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
  } else  {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
  }
}
</script>
```