# JavaScript to toggle button colour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a page with several buttons, all of which toggle from red to green when a task is completed. However, I want them to be able to toggle back if a mistake is made.  So far, I have the following function:

```html
  <button id="button">button</button>
  <script>
  function changeColor(button) {
      
        var thisButton = document.getElementById(button)

        if (thisButton.style.background == '#0f0') {
          thisButton.style.background='#0f0';
        } else {
          thisButton.style.background='#f00';
        }

      }

    </script>
```

If I use 'red' or 'green' as the colours, this works, but if I use hex as above, or rgb (255,0,0), the if always returns 'false'. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare a backgroundColor in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-a-backgroundcolor-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing background color to short-version of hex. Compare it to full 6-digits hex:

```
if (thisButton.style.background.toLowerCase() == '#00ff00')
```

But consider using some classes for that. Switching classes are much better way.

Comment: I agree, two class such as `btn-pending` and `btn-completed` would be better. it will also make the code cleaner if you you want to change more than just the color of the button. Then all you have to do is toggle the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct hex codes.

Red is `#FF0000` and green is `#008000`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the browser is "autocorrecting" the applied color. In my tests, if I set `thisButton.style.background = 'rgb(255,0,0)'` and then read the value back out with `console.log(thisButton.style.background)`, it would add a space after each comma, giving me `rgb(255, 0, 0)`. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq98puax/) for a demo.

I suggest adding a `data-color` attribute, which will be fully under your control.

```
  function changeColor(button) {
    var thisButton = document.getElementById(button)

    if (thisButton.getAttribute('data-color') === 'red') {
      thisButton.style.background='#0f0';
      thisButton.setAttribute('data-color', 'green');
    } else {
      thisButton.style.background='#f00';
      thisButton.setAttribute('data-color', 'red');
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color style property is highly dependent on the browser. Chrome might output something like `rgb(0, 255, 0)` while Internet Explorer might output `#00FF00`.

Try to hold the state of the button in your own model.

```js
const myButtonModel = {
    color: "#0F0"
};

function changeColor() {
    const buttonElement = document.getElementById("button");

    myButtonModel.color = myButtonModel.color === "#0F0" ? "#F00" : "#0F0";

    buttonElement.style.background = myButtonModel.color;
}
```

If you want to have a class instead like (btn-toggled) you can do this as follows:

```js
const buttonElement = document.getElementById("button");
buttonElement.classList.toggle("btn-toggled")
```

Answer (score -2):

It works for me, maybe try to use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementById`.