# Can I compare two RGB colors in Javascript? And how?

Tags: javascript

I try something like this:

```
if(elem.css.fill==='rgb(255,255,255)')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the value of `elem.css.fill`?

Comment: Duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-a-backgroundcolor-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle()` to get the list of possible css properties and then look for the value of `fill` style to match with the expected `rgb()` value.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('span');
let style = getComputedStyle(elem);
if (style.fill === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
  console.log('matched!');
}
```

```css
.circle {
  fill: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<span class="circle">Circle</span>
```

> Note that there is a spacing issue while you compare the `rgb()` values, where `rgb(255,255,255)` and `rgb(255, 255, 255)` is considered as different when you compare it as a string value