# change color with if statement jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Why the background color doesn't change to green?

```js
var id;
id = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function changeColor(){
  var elem= $("#target");         

  var color = elem.css('background-color');
  if (color == 'rgb(255,0,0)')
    elem.css('background-color','green');
  else
    elem.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: are you getting any console errors?, is changeColor() even running?

Comment: its running @RamondeVries

Comment: are there any !important used stylings on the #target?

Comment: Here is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60689673/383904

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var id;
id = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function changeColor(){
  var elem= $("#target");         

  var color = elem.css('background-color');
  if (color == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
    elem.css('background-color','green');
  else
    elem.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

the `if` statement was checking a wrong condition: `'rgb(255,0,0)'` vs `'rgb(255, 0, 0)'`

Comment: your code is exacly the same

Comment: nope, the if condition is different, check it carefully

Comment: just noticed the .css returns it with spaces. my bad. i was thinking about setting it works without the spaces too

Answer (score -1):

Try to check rgba instead of rgb.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Change Color</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       function changeColor(){
            var elem= $("#target");         
        
            var color = elem.css('background-color');
            
            if (color == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
                elem.css('background-color','green');
            else
                elem.css('background-color', 'red');
           
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id;
            id = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="target">Welcome to JavaScript!!!</div>
    <!--.div-row -->


</body>
```

Comment: rgb should work, and if not itll run the else anyway, still showing output