# Cannot get background style using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the simple hex code value of the `test` div. I've followed the exact same principle as with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript) post, although I'm not getting it. What should be logged into the console is the hex code `#0ff0ff`

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test'),
    window.getComputedStyle(test);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('background'));
```

```css
#test {
  background: #0ff0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks for any help here

Comment: What happens if you `.getPropertyValue('background-color')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the value of `window.getComputedStyle(test)` inside the variable `style`.

Be aware that `getPropertyValue('background-color')` returns a RGB value not a HEX code.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

var style = window.getComputedStyle(test);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
```

```css
#test {
  background: #0ff0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

Comment: RGB or non-RGB is totally up to the browser. (Modern ones return RGB/A but who knows one day one might decide to return HEX/A) @user875

Comment: Cool, didn't know that, i thought it was always RGB

Comment: Indeed :) regarding the returned values and getComputedStyle:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60689673/383904 - In case OP was after comparing colors...

Answer (score 2):

Adding RGB to HEX CODE from [theblackgigant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62693804/8960497).
RGB to Hex Code [Erick Petrucelli's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627747/8960497)

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");

//Get the color Code
  var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(test, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  
//Most browsers seem to return the RGB value
//Function to Convert RGB to Hex Code
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

//Output
console.log(rgb2hex(theCSSprop));
```

```css
#test {
  background: #0ff0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>test</div>
```