# How to assign color to Javascript variable and use it throughout the Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I want to assign the #FFCB03 to a javascript variable and use it.
Below is my code

```
let btn_all = document.getElementById("btn_all");
let btn_A = document.getElementById("btn_A");
let btn_B = document.getElementById("btn_B");
let btn_C = document.getElementById("btn_C");

btn_A.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    
    let allButtons = [btn_all, btn_A, btn_B, btn_C];
    
    function changeColor(e) {
        let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        if (currentColor != "red") {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
    
        }
    
        if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == "red" && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == "red" && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
            btn_all.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
            btn_all.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    
        if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == "") {
            btn_A.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        }
    
    
    }
```

Instead of use "red" color I want to use this "#FFCB03" color by assign it to a varible. Like this: let bgColor = "#FFCB03"; and replace it in my function, but this make my function not working as when I use "red". Even I replace "#FFCB03" directly to where "red" is, it make my function not working too.

**UPDATE**
This code is work just like what I want it to. One thing that I want to add to the code is I want to make "red" color to another color just like "#FFCB03". but when I replace the "red" color with this "#FFCB03", it make my code not working as before.

Comment: I did that, I print the color as I declared, but it make my toggle not working.

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/szmnc4w8/  if you want me to clarify problem, I'm happy to.

Comment: I have already update my question, can you make it check it again

Comment: Okay -- anyway, if you just add a `console.log` into that you'll see that the color is normalized to `rgb(...)`, but [html - How to compare colors in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-colors-in-javascript) explains it much better.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to accomplish this. I will use this code as an example.

```
<div class = "example-container"></div>
<script>
const red = "#FFCB03"; //store desired color in the variable
const div = document.querySelector(".example-div");
div.style.backgroundColor = red; //assign it
```

tada :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code like this:

```
let red = "#FFCB03";
e.target.style.backgroundColor = red;
```

and here is the code changed from your code

```
let btn_all = document.getElementById("btn_all");
let btn_A = document.getElementById("btn_A");
let btn_B = document.getElementById("btn_B");
let btn_C = document.getElementById("btn_C");

let red = "#FFCB03";

btn_A.style.backgroundColor = red;
    
    let allButtons = [btn_all, btn_A, btn_B, btn_C];
    
    function changeColor(e) {
        let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        if (currentColor != red) {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = red;
        }
        else {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
    
        }
    
        if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == red && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == red && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == red) {
            btn_all.style.backgroundColor = red;
        } else {
            btn_all.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    
        if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == "") {
            btn_A.style.backgroundColor = red
        }
    
    
    }
```

Could this code solve your problem?

Comment: first, I think it was that simple but no luck. It not work.

Comment: I tried some sample in my environment and maybe found the root cause.

Comment: When you click the button "all"
you will execute a code :
xxx.style.backgroundColor
But this code will output the result : "rgb(255, 203, 3)"

So it will not output the "#FFCB03" but a new rgb format.
Maybe  you should compare the color with "rgb(255, 203, 3)" and try again

Comment: let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    if (currentColor != "red")


Above is the issue position, maybe you should change it to 

let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    if (currentColor != "rgb(255, 203, 3)")

Comment: This means I have to compare with rgb instead of using #FFCB03 directly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file as `colors.js` or something and store and export the values from there

### Multiple modules

```js
export const red = `#FFCB03`;
```

other files

```
import { red } from './colors'

btn_A.style.backgroundColor = red
```

### Same Module or file

In case of same file, just declare the variable and use it

```html
<script>
  const red = `#FFCB03`;


  btn_A.style.backgroundColor = red
</script>
```