# Removing a red border on mobile Chrome with Jquery/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a red border from a div which is being used to highlight validation errors.  I want to replace the border with a transparency so when an element with the `.swatches` class is clicked the border is "removed".

This code does work (including the commented out lines) however this issue is appearing on Mobile Chrome.

Any idea what the issue could be?

The classes `cf` and `colour-form-field` don't have any styles associated with them.

```
$('.swatches').click(function(){
    removeValidationBorder('#optionHolder', 'transparent'); //#f8f8f8
});
```

This is my function.

```
function removeValidationBorder(el, color) {
    console.log('removeValidationBorder');
    //if ($(el).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' || $(el).css('color') == 'red') {
    if ($(el).css('color') != color) {
        console.log('colors do not match');
        //$(el).css('border','2px solid ' + color);
        $(el).css({"border-width" : "2px", "border-style" : "solid", "border-color" : color});
    }
}
```

Here's the `HTML`:

```
<div id="optionHolder" class="cf colour-form-field" style="border: 2px solid transparent; margin-bottom: 4px;">
    <div id="colOptions" class="form-label">
      <h6>Select a colour: <span id="selectedColor">Silver - add £10.00</span></h6>
     </div>
     <ul class="swatches">
       <li id="productSwatch_83995"><a id="photoswitch_76171" title="Natural" href="#"><img src="images/products/options/76166_swatch.png" width="46" height="36" alt="Natural" title="Natural" border="0"><p><span>Natural</span></p></a></li>
       <li id="productSwatch_83996"><a id="photoswitch_76172" title="Black" href="#"><img src="images/products/options/76167_swatch.png" width="46" height="36" alt="Black" title="Black" border="0"><p><span>Black - add £10.00</span></p></a></li>
       <li id="productSwatch_83997"><a id="photoswitch_76173" title="Sand" href="#"><img src="images/products/options/76168_swatch.png" width="46" height="36" alt="Sand" title="Sand" border="0"><p><span>Sand - add £10.00</span></p></a></li>
       <li id="productSwatch_83998"><a id="photoswitch_76174" title="Cappuccino" href="#"><img src="images/products/options/76169_swatch.png" width="46" height="36" alt="Cappuccino" title="Cappuccino" border="0"><p><span>Cappuccino - add £10.00</span></p></a></li>
       <li id="productSwatch_83999" class="selected"><a id="photoswitch_76175" title="Silver" href="#"><img src="images/products/options/76170_swatch.png" width="46" height="36" alt="Silver" title="Silver" border="0"><p><span>Silver - add £10.00</span></p></a></li>
   </ul>                        

<input type="hidden" name="options[1]" value="83999" id="photoOptionDropDown">
</div>
```

Comment: Some browsers do not support *transparent* for `border-color`. Have you checked if it works when you apply another color, e.g. *white*?

Comment: Yeah I tried the `#f8f8f8` color it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Your comparation of colors in line `($(el).css('color') != color)` will not work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11943970/4571082) for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because `.click` has been deprecated for mobile chrome.  I couldn't use jquery mobile so called my function like so:

```
$('#selectedColor').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    removeValidationBorder('#optionHolder', 'transparent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var color = none;
```

and `border` will be broken, and will not be showing.

Comment: You mean `var color='none';` or `border-color: none;`, right?