# If statement is always false even if the condition is true in java script

Tags: javascript

this is the javascript and HTML and CSS I m very  new to javascript the problem is if statement is always showing wrong even though it should not if statement is always false even if I click on the value of the color of win variable that the value of the 3rd index of the array colors its showing wrong

```js
var colors = [
 "rgb(255,0,0)",
 "rgb(255,255,0)",
 "rgb(0,255,0)",
 "rgb(0,255,255)",
 "rgb(0,0,255)",
 "rgb(255,0,255)"
 ]
var win =colors[3];
var winclrdisplay=document.querySelector(".winclr");
var square= document.querySelectorAll(".square");

 winclrdisplay.textContent=" "+ win;
 
 for (var  i = 0 ;i < square.length ; i++){
  //colors 
  square[i].style.background =colors[i];
  
  // click listener
  square[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   var click = this.style.background;
   if (click == win){
    alert("correct");
   }else{
    alert("wrong");
   }
  }
   );
 }
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #232323;
}

.square{
 width: 30%;
 background: purple;
 padding-bottom: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;


}

#container {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>color guessing game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorapp.css">

</head>
<body>
 <h1>The Great <span class="winclr"></span> colour Game</h1>
 
<div id="container">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to do a `console.log(click)` to see what value you are _actually_ getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two color values in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377696/how-can-i-compare-two-color-values-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: consider writing the colors in hexadecimal code, which can be compared as a string

Comment: @CBroe: No, he/she wants to use the powerful debugger built into the browser to see what he/she is actually getting. No need to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can turn on the lights with the debugger.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Re my formatting comment above: I tried to fix it for you, but it looks like you have two copies of everything? Please use the "edit" link to remove anything redundant, and to correctly handle code blocks. Or better yet, use a Stack Snippet to make a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have taken your udemy course i think you are good man though idk whats wrong with my code plus i new to stack overflow too need help what should i do

Comment: @SimSheeraz: I don't recall creating a udemy course. What's wrong is clearly called out in my comments above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I might have confused you with someone well now I added the code snippet run it and see yourself want the if statement to be true when I click on cyan color but it's false I  don't understand why

Comment: @SimSheeraz: Over half an hour ago, [CBroe pointed out what was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377696/how-can-i-compare-two-color-values-in-jquery-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

use element.getComputedStyle. element.style gets the value if the css style is inline. It is always false because it has no value.

something like this

```
var element = document.getElementById('box'),
            style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
            bg = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

    console.log(bg);
```

Comment: what is an window element colorapp.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (colorapp.js:23)

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to understand your question as it is not well formatted. But from a quick look you are missing a closing `)` in your `if` statment

```
if (click == "rgb(0,255,255"){
```

should be

```
if (click == "rgb(0,255,255)"){
```

or

```
if (click == rgb(0,255,255)){
```

(again, I'm not sure what your are aiming at)

Comment: the last one leads to an error, because `rgb(...)` will not be defined..

Comment: I believe he's just trying to get the rgb color of where he is clicking on the page.

Comment: yes i am trying to get the colour from the page on clicking on the different boxes

Comment: I added the code snippet may be now you understand  see yourself want the if statement to be true when I click on cyan color but it's false I don't understand why