# Accessing a style property while using AngularJS to set styles dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to let the user set styles dynamically, but I also want to grab the values of certain styles.  For example, I want to check if the user sets the color of an H1 element to 'orange'.

**My HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">    
    <h1 id="myH1">Hello World!</h1>

    <textarea ng-model="outputCss"></textarea>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      {{outputCss}}
    </style>   
</body>
```

**My Javascript, in mainController**

```
var myH1Style = document.getElementById('myH1').style;

$scope.$watch('outputCss', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if (myH1Style.color == "orange"){
      alert("Nice work!");
    }
    console.log(myH1Style.color);
});
```

**Example User  Input**

```
#myH1 {
color: orange;
}

h1 {
font-weight: 900;
}
```

The problem is, the if condition can never be met, and the console log is always empty.  How can I read CSS properties that are added using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is basically two questions:

1. [How do I compare colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377696/how-can-i-compare-two-color-values-in-jquery-javascript) (Sadly, the answer here is that it's ugly, the value you get back is probably not in the format in which it was applied, so you might get `"orange"` or `"rgb(255, 165, 0)"` or `"rgb(255,165,0)"` or `"rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)"`...)
2. [How do I get the styles as applied by CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

The combination of the answers to those questions answers your question. Basically, you need to use `getComputedStyle(element)` (or `element.currentStyle` on old IE) to get the *computed* style (`.style` only gives you the styles *directly* applied to the element), and the value you get back may well not be in the format that it is in the stylesheet (but in some browsers may be, hence...ugly).

---

Side note: A hardcoded `id` value is a red flag. Use [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

even before telling that you are comparing the colors in wrong manner, first of all `document.getElementById('myH1').style;` will a return the inline style, not the style applyed by CSS rules. and you are dynamically changing CSS rule and watching the inline style against that.